# listings: General settings for a language seem to be overwritten/not respected

Tags: listings

I struggle with the following `listings` styles. I have code of two different languages
(R and LaTeX) in my .tex file. As some settings are the same for R listings and
LaTeX listings, I define the style "all". It should be respected by
any `\begin{lstlisting} .. \end{lstlisting}`. I therefore use `style=all` in the
`lstset` definitions for the two languages. Then, there are additional, language
specific settings, which should also be respected. However, as you can see, that
does not quite work. Although I set the keywords in the R listings to just be
`if`, `else`, or `function`, lapply and sapply get a blue color as well. Why? And how
can this be solved?

It seems like I would have to repeat all the definitions in the optional
argument of the `lstlisting` environment. But it's tedious to do this every
time, that's why I wanted to define styles in the first place. Also, it's not clear to me why a setting like `keywords` is overwritten since the optional argument of `lstlisting` does not contain `keywords=...`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\xdefinecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}
\xdefinecolor{red}{RGB}{255, 0, 0}

% this style should be active for all lstlistings environments
\lstdefinestyle{all}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  frame=lrtb, framerule=1pt, framexleftmargin=1pt,
  showstringspaces=false
}

% this style should be active (additionally to "all") for "input" lstlistings environments
\lstdefinestyle{input}{
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

% listings settings for LaTeX in general [this is not respected!]
\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  style=all,
  keywords={},
  otherkeywords={}
}

% listings settings for R (should hold for all R listings in general)
\lstset{
  language=R,
  style=all,
  literate={<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}2,% this is respected
  keywords={if, else, function},% this is not respected
  otherkeywords={}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[{language=[LaTeX]TeX}, style=input]
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo % bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R, style=input]
x <- 4
s <- lapply(1:10, function(z) z+x)
k <- sapply(1:10, function(z) z+2*x) # other case
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just set general rules with `lstset` and create two language styles, which you may use then together with the input style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to think that `\lstset` sets parameters for one specified language, i.e., the language given within `\lstset`. That is not how it works. Your code first sets the default language for all listings of your document to `TeX`, then it sets it to `R`, and so on. Similarly, it sets three default keywords for all listings of your document (if, else, function), but when you typeset your R listing, the keyword list that belongs to R overwrites the default keyword list.

What you actually want is probably best achived with styles, or you define a new language based on R, or a new dialect of R. Let's try with styles:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

% this style should be active for all lstlistings environments
\lstdefinestyle{all}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  frame=lrtb, framerule=1pt, framexleftmargin=1pt,
  showstringspaces=false
}

% this style should be active (additionally to "all") for "input" lstlistings environments
\lstdefinestyle{input}{
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\lstdefinestyle{newLaTeXsettings}{
  style=all,
  keywords={},
  otherkeywords={}
}


% listings settings for R (should hold for all R listings in general)
\lstdefinestyle{newRsettings}{
  style=all,
  literate={<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}2,% this is respected
  keywords={if, else, function},% this is not respected
  otherkeywords={}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}, style=input, style=newLaTeXsettings]
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo % bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R, style=input, style=newRsettings]
x <- 4
s <- lapply(1:10, function(z) z+x)
k <- sapply(1:10, function(z) z+2*x) # other case
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, mafp. Why are the words "begin", "item", and "end" still blue although `newLaTeXSettings` resets the keywords?

Comment: @MariusHofert The reason is that the TeX dialects don't have keywords, but `texcs`'s (for *tex control sequences*). Here, even after resetting the keywords, `begin`, `item`, and `end` are still valid texcs. To get rid of them, use `texcs={...}`, `moretexcs={...}`, `deletetexcs={...}`, just as with keywords.

Answer (score 3):

If you have certain priorities in your style settings you MUST load them in the right order. Cause `style=...` will just output the list given in `\lstdefinestyle` so the latter style will rule.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}


% priority: low
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  frame=lrtb, framerule=1pt, framexleftmargin=1pt,
  showstringspaces=false
}
% priority: mid
\lstdefinestyle{input}{
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}
% priority major
\lstdefinestyle{mylatex}{%
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
 keywordstyle={\color{black}},% just redoing what input would do to us. 
  otherkeywords={}%
}

\lstdefinestyle{myr}{
  language=R,
  literate={<-}{{$\leftarrow$}}2,% this is respected
  keywords={if, else, function},% this is not respected
  otherkeywords={}
}



\begin{document}
%low priority must be loaded befor higher priorities. 
%so that i can be overwritten. 
\begin{lstlisting}[ style=input, style=mylatex, ]
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo % bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=input,style=myr, ]
x <- 4
s <- lapply(1:10, function(z) z+x)
k <- sapply(1:10, function(z) z+2*x if)     # other case
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

All general rules are set with `lstset` and in force until a local command (given as `style` or actual optional argument to the environment ) will overwrite it. So here i created three levels. First to come are the global (low priority) options. You won't feel the need to care about them much. The second level is the `input` style, which shall be overwritten by the `lang` style. This style will rule at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bloodworks. I am still wondering why `keywords={}` instead of `keywordstyle={\color{black}}` does not work (begin end etc. are still blue). If there are no keywords, there shouldn't be anything blue, right? Hmmm...

Comment: I never took a deeper look into the source of listings since i'm not very fond of catcode hackery. I could imagine, that it's simply to late then to unload the keywordlist. Furthermore it`s known that listings treats tex code a bit different form other (eg R) code. Is painting them simply black not  sufficient for you?